# Disable GridView items on click

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridView` that is generated dynamically from SQLite database entries. An activity is started when a user taps on one of the `GridView` items. During the time from the tap and the activity launch, there is a split second where the user can rapidly tap other `Gridview` items which initiates their `onItemClick`method. Is there a way so all the `GridView` items `onItemClick` methods are disabled after selecting one?

Here is the code:

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
nautsList = db.getAllNauts();
nautsGridAdapter = new AwesomenautGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.gridview_item, nautsList);
gridView.setAdapter(nautsGridAdapter);

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
         //do stuff
         Intent intent = new Intent(AwesomenautSelectionActivity.this, AwesomenautSoundActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this simple solution. It is successfully used in our apps.
Make a global boolean `itemsLocked` and set it to true as soon as you click. Set it back to false just before startActivity. Finally, in method `onItemClick` add

```
if (itemsLocked) return;
```

EDIT: method `onItemClick`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
    if (itemsLocked) return;
    itemsLocked = true;

    //do stuff
    Intent intent = new Intent(...);
    itemsLocked = false;
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Such a nice, simple, elegant solution! Works perfectly. Many thanks